# prove that the set: $|x|+|y|<1$ is open

Tags: real-analysis

prove that the set: $|x|+|y|<1$ is open
this is analysis problem. I know every neighborhood is included in the set to become an open set, but I don't know how to elaborate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x,y)=|x|+|y|$ this function is continuous. $(-\infty,1)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. The set we are considering is the reciprocal image of that open set precisely $f^{-1}((-\infty,1))$ and is therefore open

Answer (score 1):

Let $O=\{(x,y) : |x|+|y|\leq 1\}$ and let $(x_0,y_0)\in O$ be arbitrary. It is enough to find $r_0$ such that the ball $B_{r_0}(x_0,y_0)$ with center at $(x_0,y_0)$ and radius $r_0$ entirely is contained in $O$.
Let $r$ be the minimum distance of the point $(x_0,y_0)$ from the lines $x+y=1$, $x-y=1$, $-x+y=1$ and $-x-y=1$.  It is not hard to show that $B_{r_0}(x_0,y_0)\subset O$ for all $r_0< r$.